# No se como quitar una línea de un .bat

Tags: batch, .bat

buenas.
Estoy buscando la forma de llamar a un archivo .bat desde otro archivo .bat, pero sin que que aparezca la línea del prompt entre la ejecución de uno de los archivos y el otro.
Mi idea es crear un .bat con el nombre de *titulo.bat* y poder reutilizarlo en otros archivos de la misma extensión llamándolo.
El código sería el siguiente:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Script del titulo que se reutilizara

ECHO ******************
ECHO *     Prueba     *
ECHO ******************
```

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Programa principal

ECHO PUNTO DE CONTROL 1
START /B titulo.bat
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NULL

ECHO PUNTO DE CONTROL 2
SET /A NUM1=10
SET /A NUM2=37
SET /A RESUL=%NUM1%*%NUM2%

ECHO PUNTO DE CONTROL 3
ECHO %RESUL%
ECHO PUNTO DE CONTROL 4
EXIT
```

Y por último el resultado:

```
C:\Users\alexb\Desktop>main.bat
PUNTO DE CONTROL 1
******************
*     Prueba     *
******************

C:\Users\extabecerra\Desktop>PUNTO DE CONTROL 2
PUNTO DE CONTROL 3
370
PUNTO DE CONTROL 4

C:\Users\extabecerra\Desktop>
```

Lo que busco es quitar la línea que aparece rodeada en rojo, que entiendo que aparece porque el archivo *titulo.bat* termina su ejecución.
[image: Foto de los dos archivos y el resultado]

Comment: Utiliza CALL titulo.bat

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, poniendo CALL desaparece esa línea molesta :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando el comando `CALL` en vez de `START`, esa línea no sólo desaparece si no que lo que contenga el archivo *título.bat* se ejecutará directamente en la propia consola sin abrir una nueva. Por lo que así evitamos poner `START /B` que haría la misma función pero mostrando la línea del prompt.
Créditos para [Juan Carlos Guibovich](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/152765/juan-carlos-guibovich)